# Core plot objective-c, i want to make range of y-axis of my graph similar to excel graph automatic axis range/scaling

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am making a graph in objective-c by using core plot library. i want to make my graph`s y-axis automatic scale like in excel the range produced automatically.

Axis format in excel:

```
minimum: auto
maximum: auto
major unit: auto
minor unit: auto
major tick mark type: outside
minor tick mark type: none
axis labels: next to Axis
```

I tried `yAxis.labelPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` but I didnt produced same range as excel graph is producing.

Answer (score 2):

The labeling policy handles making the labels but doesn't affect the scale of the axis. For that you need to use the plot space. The `-scaleToFitPlots:` method will adjust both the x and y ranges so that they exactly fit the data for all of the plots in the array. For example, to make the default plot space fit all plots in the graph, use

```
[graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I want to have the range values always similar to excel producing range values. Excel is defining the range automatically I want the same scaling/range like excel.

Comment: I have only one plot in my graph this method [graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]]; is not working for me. My plot is not autoResizing, How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not changing the ranges at all, or it's not giving you the numbers that you want? Core Plot axis scaling works differently than Excel axis scaling.

Comment: WHat about the labels?  You seem to have to specify the labels and locations of the axis labels.

Comment: @shim, it depends on the labeling policy. You only need to provide custom labels with labeling policy "none". You supply the tick locations for "none" and "locations provided".